# How to solve the below system of congruence?

Tags: systems-of-equations, divisibility, congruences

I have tried to solve the below congruence system but i don't succeed , such that i have wrote  $3x+5y=6$ as $5y =-3x²\mod (6)$ then i can't  write this  equation as : $y= z \bmod 6$ in order to solve this system , Then my question here is

> > **Question**
> >     How to solve this system :
> >     $$
> > \begin{cases}
> > 3x+5y=6 \\
> > y \equiv x² \pmod{5}
> > \end{cases}
> > $$

Answer (score 0):

We have that

- $3x+5y=6 \implies 3x\equiv 1 \mod 5\implies x\equiv 2 \mod 5$
- $y \equiv x² \pmod{5}\implies y \equiv 4 \pmod{5}$

then one solution is given by

- $3(2+5k)+5(4+5j)=6\implies 15k+25 j=-20\implies3k+5j=-4\\\implies k=2\quad j=-2$

and therefore

- $x=12$
- $y=-6$

Note that since $gdc(3,5)=1$, by Bezout's identity, the equation $3k+5j=-4$ has infinitely many solutions, notably $\forall m\in \mathbb{Z}$

$$3(2)+5(-2)=-4\implies 3(2+5m)+5(-2-3m)=-4 $$

thus all the pairs

- $k=2+5m$
- $j=-2-3m$

leads to different solutions

- $x=12+25m$
- $y=-6-15m$

Answer (score 0):

I would solve first the linear diophantine equation $\;3x+5y=6$. The method is standard:

- First step: solve $\;3x+5y=1$.

Start from a *Bézout's relation* between $3$ and $5$:
$$ 2\times 3-1\cdot 5=1. $$
All other solutions have the form
$$x=2+5k,\quad y=-1-3k\qquad(k\in\mathbf Z).$$

- Second step: deduce the solutions of $\;3x+5y=6$.

A basic solution is obtained multiplying the basic solution of the previous equation by $6$: $\; x_0=12,\;y_0=-6$, and the general solution, as in the previous case, is
$$x=12+5k,\quad y=-6-3k\qquad(k\in\mathbf Z).$$

- Quadratic congruence: as $x \equiv 2\mod 5$, $\;y\equiv x^2\equiv -1\mod 5$. In terms of $k$, this means
  $$y=-6-3k\equiv-1-3k\equiv -1\mod 5 \iff 3k\equiv 0\iff k\equiv 0\mod 5,$$
  since $3$ is a unit mod. $5$. Thus $k=5\ell\enspace (\ell\in\mathbf Z)$, and finally
  $$x=12+25\ell,\quad y=-6-15\ell\qquad(\ell\in\mathbf Z). $$

Answer (score 0):

$3x + 5y = 6$.  As $\gcd(3,5) = 1$, by Bezouts Theorem there are an infinite number of solutions.

$3x = 6 - 5y$

$x = 2 - \frac {5y}3$.  So $3|y$.  Let $y = 3k$ then

$x = 2 - 5k$.  So all solutions are $\{(2 - 5k, 3k)\}$

$y \equiv x^2 \mod 5$

$3k \equiv (2-5k)^2 \mod 5$

$3k \equiv 4 \mod 5$

$2*3k \equiv 2*4 \mod 5$

$k \equiv 3 \mod 5$.

So $k = 2 + 5m$ for some $m$ and $x = 2- 5(2-5m) = -8 + 25m$ and $y = 3(2+5m) = 6 + 15m$.

So all possible solutions are $\{(-8 + 25m, 6+15m)\}$.